# R: Subscripts in pie chart using Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart

I am trying to plot some air pollutants data using R `Plotly` package. So far, I am able to achieve this.

```
library(plotly)
val <- c(10, 12,4, 16, 8)
ap <- c("NO2", "PM10", "PM2.5", "NOx", "SO2")
plot_ly(labels = ~ap, values = ~val, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'label')
```

[image: Output]

I would like to improve this pie-chart. I want to show '`10`' in `PM10` as subscript and write "custom text" next to label. My expected outcome: `PM[10] (47%)` and so on. Someone care to explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to setup subscripts and custom hover text in plotly:

```
library(plotly)
val <- c(10, 12,4, 16, 8)
ap <- c("NO<sub>2</sub>", "PM<sub>10</sub>", "PM<sub>2.5</sub>", "NO<sub>x</sub>", "SO<sub>[2]</sub>")
```

For subscripts one needs to add `<sub>` prior and `</sub>` afterward the text.

Custom hovers are obtained by defining `text` argument in `plot_ly` call

```
plot_ly(labels = ~ap, values = ~val, type = 'pie',
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste0(val *100/sum(val), '%'),
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'label')
```

If changing the labels was desired without the hover:

```
plot_ly(labels = ~paste(ap, paste0('[', val *100/sum(val), '%]')),
        values = ~val, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'label')
```

[image]

Comment: First, I think, <sub>SO[2]</sub> should be SO<sub>2</sub>. Isn't it?

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch =)

Comment: What if I want to write custom text as % in labels? For example, NO[2] (my_custom %). Is it possible?

Comment: @Jibran Khan yes it is possible, just supply a vector of custom text strings of the same length as the labels and paste it together.